# Can I open and run from multiple command line prompts in the same directory?

Tags: command-line, cmder

I want to open two command line prompts (I am using CMDer) from the same directory and run different commands at the same time. 
Would those two commands interrupt each other? 
One is for compiling a web application I am building (takes like 7 minutes to compile), and the other is to see the history of the commands I ran (this one should be done quickly).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that CMDer does nothing else than to issue the same commands to the operating system as a standard cmd.exe console would do, then the answer is a clear "Yes, they do interfere, but it depends" :D

Break down:

The first part "opening multiple consoles" is certainly possible. You can open up N console windows and in each of them switch to the same directory without any problems (Except maybe RAM restrictions).

The second part "run commands which do or do not interfere" is the tricky part. If your idea is that a console window presents you something like an isolated environment where you can do things as you like and if you close the window everything is back to normal as if you never ever touched anything (think of a virtual machine snapshot which is lost/reverted when closing the VM) - then the answer is: This is not the case. There will be cross console effects observable.

Think about deleting a file in one console window and then opening this file in a second console window: It would not be very intuitive if the file would not have been vanished in the second console window as well.
However, sometimes there are delays until changes to the file system are visible to another console window. It could be, that you delete the file in one console and make a `dir` where the file is sitting in another console and still see that file in the listing. But if you try to access it, the operating system will certainly quit with an error message of the kind "File not found".

Generally you should consider a console window to be a "View" on your system. If you do something in one window, the effect will be present in the other, because you changed the underlying system which exists only once (the system is the "Model" - as in "Model-View-Controller Design Pattern" you may have heard of).
An exception to this might be changes to the environment variables. These are copied from the current state when a console window is started. And if you change the value of such a variable, the other console windows will stay unaffected.

So, in your scenario, if you let a build/compile operation run and during this process some files on your file system are created, read (locked), altered or deleted then this would be a possible conflicting situation if the other console window tries to access the same files. It will be a so called "race condition", that is, a non-deterministic process, which state of a file will be actual to the second console window (or both, if the second one also changes files which the first one wants to work with). 
If there is no interference on a file level (reading the same files is allowed, writing to the same file is not), then there should be no problem of letting both tasks run at the same time.

However, on a very detailed view, both processes would interfere in that they need the same limited but vastly available CPU and RAM resources of your system. This should not pose any problems with the todays PC computing power, considering features like X separate cores, 16GB of RAM, Terabytes of hard drive storage or fast SSDs, and so on.
Unless there is a very demanding, highly parallelizable, high priority task to be considered, which eats up 98% CPU time, for example. Then there might be a considerable slow down impact on other processes.
Normally, the operating system's scheduler does a good job on giving each user-process enough CPU time to finish as quickly as possible, while still presenting a responsive mouse cursor, playing some music in the background, allowing a Chrome running with more than 2 tabs ;) and uploading the newest telemetry data to some servers on the internet, all at the same time.

There are techniques which make it possible that a file is available as certain snapshots to a given timestamp. The key word would be "Shadow Copy" under Windows. Without going into details, this technique allows for example defragmenting a file while it is being edited in some application or a backup could copy a (large) file while a delete operation is run at the same file. The operating system ensures that the access time is considered when a process requests access to a file. So the OS could let the backup finish first, until it schedules the delete operation to run, since this was started after the backup (in this example) or could do even more sophisticated things to present a synchronized file system state, even if it is actually changing at the moment.